# PySpark dynamic creation of StructType

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, delta-lake

I have a situation where my data looks like this:

| id | values | schema |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | {'colA':3.2, 'colB':'val2', 'colC':3.4} | {'colA':'FLOAT', 'colB':'STRING', 'colC':'FLOAT'} |
| 3 | {'colC':3.2, 'colX':3.9} | {'colC':'FLOAT', 'colX':'FLOAT'} |
| 4 | {'colG':'val1', 'colH':93.2} | {'colG':'STRING', 'colH':'FLOAT'} |
| 5 | {'colG':'val4', 'colA':4.2, 'colJ':93.2, 'colM':'val4'} | {'colG':'STRING', 'colA':'FLOAT', 'ColJ':'FLOAT', 'ColM':'STRING'} |

Both the `values` and `schema` columns are originally stored as `StringType`. I would like to convert the `values` column to a `StructType` where each possible key is defined. The final schema should look like below:

```
 |-- id: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- values: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- colA: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- colB: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- colC: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- colG: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- colH: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- colJ: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- colM: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- colX: double (nullable = true)
```

My question is, is it possible to get to this schema without explicitly specifying it? In the example I showed we are talking about a few columns and, but in the actual case it are a few 100s of columns. Ideally I would like to infer the schema without the original `schema` column, but it is not a big issue if this column needs to be used (Note that the datatypes in the schema column do not necessarily match spark datatypes. The data needs to be stored in delta.

Will this be possible, or will there not be another option than storing it as MapType(StringType, StringType)?

The code I used for creating a test dataframe

```
data = [
    (
        2,
        "{'colA':3.2, 'colB':'val2', 'colC':3.4}",
        "{'colA':'FLOAT', 'colB':'STRING', 'colC':'FLOAT}",
    ),
    (
        3, 
        "{'colC':3.2, 'colX':3.9}", 
        "{'colC':'FLOAT', 'colX':'FLOAT'}"),
    (
        4, 
        "{'colG':'val1', 'colH':93.2}", 
        "{'colG':'STRING', 'colH':'FLOAT'}"),
    (
        5,
        "{'colG':'val4', 'colA':4.2, 'colJ':93.2, 'colM':'val4'}",
        "{'colG':'STRING', 'colA':'FLOAT', 'ColJ':'FLOAT', 'ColM':'STRING'}",
    ),
]

schema = T.StructType(
    [
        T.StructField("id", T.IntegerType()),
        T.StructField("values", T.StringType()),
        T.StructField("schema", T.StringType()),
    ]
)

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you could create a schema string for the target columns and use `from_json` to parse `values` field.

example

```py
# create target schema
jsonsch = data_sdf. \
    groupBy(func.lit(1).alias('dropme')). \
    agg(func.array_join(func.collect_list('schema'), ',').alias('allsch')). \
    withColumn('allsch', func.regexp_replace('allsch', '\},\{', ', ')). \
    select('allsch'). \
    collect()[0][0]

# "{'colA':'FLOAT', 'colB':'STRING', 'colC':'FLOAT', 'colC':'FLOAT', 'colX':'FLOAT', 'colG':'STRING', 'colH':'FLOAT', 'colG':'STRING', 'colA':'FLOAT', 'colJ':'FLOAT', 'colM':'STRING'}"

import json

jsonschema = ', '.join([k[0]+' '+k[1].lower() for k in json.loads(jsonsch.replace("'", '"')).items()])

# "colA float, colB string, colC float, colX float, colG string, colH float, colJ float, colM string"

# parse the `values` column using the target schema
data_sdf. \
    withColumn('parsed_val', func.from_json('values', jsonschema)). \
    selectExpr('id', 'parsed_val'). \
    show(truncate=False)

# +---+------------------------------------------------+
# |id |parsed_val                                      |
# +---+------------------------------------------------+
# |2  |{3.2, val2, 3.4, null, null, null, null, null}  |
# |3  |{null, null, 3.2, null, null, null, null, 3.9}  |
# |4  |{null, null, null, val1, 93.2, null, null, null}|
# |5  |{4.2, null, null, val4, null, 93.2, val4, null} |
# +---+------------------------------------------------+

# root
#  |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
#  |-- parsed_val: struct (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- colA: float (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- colB: string (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- colC: float (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- colG: string (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- colH: float (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- colJ: float (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- colM: string (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- colX: float (nullable = true)
```

Comment: amazing, this works! Curious about the performance on large amounts of data. I'll test it in the coming days